# React native conditional rendering an array with 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array with several objects. Inside each object i have a field called type that can be either a or b. I am trying to conditional render a specific view for type a and a specific view for type b.

Here is my array:

```
DATA=[
{id:1, type:'a'},{id:2,type:'b'}
]

return(
{DATA.type === 'a' ?

<Text>I am type A</Text>
:
<Text>I am Type B </Text>
}
)
```

When i do that nothing appears on the screen.

UPDATE

```
DATA=[
{id:1, type:'a',locked:true},
{id:2,type:'b',locked:false}
]

const[isLocked,setIsLocked]=useState(false)

return(

{isLocked && DATA.map((item) => item.type === 'a')) ?

<Text>I am type A</Text>
:
null}
)
```

it is still not working. I am type A still appears on all pages of my carousel.

Comment: `DATA` is an array. You will need to use index like `DATA[0].type === 'a' ? ...`

Comment: @Karan i dont want to specify the object because i am using a carousel

Comment: @Karan hi can you please look at my updated question

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your array to accomplish it. Otherwise, you can't get the correct key.

```
DATA = [
  { id:1, type:a },
  { id:2, type:b },
]

return(
  DATA.map((item) => item.type === 'a' 
    ? <Text>I am type A</Text>
    : <Text>I am Type B </Text>
))
```

Comment: It is still not working.

Comment: Be sure that your syntax for array creation (for RN) is:

`const DATA = [
  { id:1, type:"a" },
  { id:2, type:"b" },
]`

Comment: this is an typo mistake in my question. Still not workinh